# Split a list every nth element

Tags: r

I would like to split a list regularly every n elements. For example:

```
a <- 1:9
```

Then split the list every 3 elements.

Result:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 4 5 6

[[3]]
[1] 7 8 9
```

Comment: `split(1:9, rep(1:3, each = 3))`

Comment: Thank you! The previous answer didn't come up with my search terms.

Comment: Actually, I disagree that this is an exact duplicate. The supposed equivalent answer is splitting by percentile which is very clearly not what I am doing here.

Comment: Fair enough, although your answer is far from elegant for answering my specific question. It is good to have the answer of @Alistaire on the record.